# ArrayList from class objects simpler way to do?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I know how to put class objects to an `ArrayList` in java (since new objects can be appended without knowledge of an index first) but I was wondering if there is a simpler way of adding them to an `ArrayList` and iterating over them?

I was even thinking that, hypothetically, if I kept my object names in a pattern, that I should be able to add each object to the list using a loop e.g. `car1, car2, car3, ...`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestCar {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> carNames = new ArrayList<>();
        // Cars have simple getter methods corresponding with String and int
        Car car1 = new Car("Rav4", 2017);
        carNames.add(car1.getName());
        Car car2 = new Car("Commodore", 2005);
        carNames.add(car2.getName());

        for (int i = 0; i < carNames.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(carNames.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

As always, thanks for any replies!

Comment: You can use `addAll`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do from your example code, you have a number of separate objects you want to add to a list is that correct? Or are they connected somehow?

Comment: You can use an `ArrayList<Car>` and if you just want the names, use the answer given by @Eritrean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8 or higher, you could add your `Car` objects to a list and use streams to get a list of `carNames` :

```
List<Car> myCarList = Arrays.asList( new Car("Rav4", 2017), new Car("Commodore", 2005));
List<String> carNames = myCarList.stream()
                                 .map(Car::getName)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So OP should add the objects to a list to be able to add them to another list?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sometimes the ways of the lord are inscrutable. So are the ways of java. Just kidding. I think rather a `Car` object has usually a few more fields. If he has the whole object in a list he can map it to any attribute e.g. `Car::getMake`, `Car::getManufacturer`, `Car::getId`  etc.

Comment: That was not the point of my comment, why create 2 lists instead of just one directly? There is nothing gained from your solution, you could just do `List<String> carNames = Arrays.asList( "Rav4", "Commodore");`